# Why do people tend write "RAW" instead of "raw"?

Tags: raw, terminology

Given that in the English language using all-caps means that the word is an  acronyms or initialism (e.g., NASA, RCMP), "RAW" doesn't make much sense--unless there's some longer term that "RAW" stands form. Strictly speaking, shouldn't the term be *raw image(s)*?

Comment: See also [What, if anything, does "RAW" stand for?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/what-if-anything-does-raw-stand-for)